# Display selected color in the menu

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application the user can select a color. Default color is yellow, but any color can be selected. I would like to display the currently selected color in the menu as shown in the picture below.

[image: Selected color is now yellow]

How can this be done? I tried using a transparent gif and then changing the ImageTransparentColor, but that somehow doesn't show the result.

EDIT

I now realize that my question wasn't clear enough - sorry.

How to display an image next to the menuitem is not the problem. What I want to achieve is that each time when a user selects a (different) color, the selected color should be shown next to the menuItem. Preferably without having to load an image everytime (which doesn't really make sense, since the user can select any RGB-combination he wants).
I had thought I could add an image and then set some kind of overlay with the selected color on top of that image.

Comment: Are you using ToolStripMenuItems ?

Comment: Yes I am - pls see the edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by using John Wood's reply to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779519/best-way-to-create-button-displaying-selected-color?rq=1):

(1) Overriding the Paint-method for this menuItem

```
     public Form1()
     {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Override the paint-method for the menuItem
        selectColorToolStripMenuItem.Paint += OnDrawItem;
     }
```

(2) drawing a box from scratch:

```
    protected void OnDrawItem(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        Pen mPen = new Pen(bgColor, 10);
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(10,10);
        Graphics g1 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g1.DrawRectangle(mPen, 0, 0, 10, 10);
        selectColorToolStripMenuItem.Image = bmp;

    }
```

Quite simple after all...